# Flex 4.5 Spark Datagrid multi-column sort

Tags: sorting, apache-flex, datagrid, multiple-columns, flex-spark

does anyboy know if Flex 4.5 Spark Datagrid suppoprts multi-column sort natively - just like the ADG does?

I'm looking at the api documentation and cannot see anything on this...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not natively no.  There's constant improvements being done on the charting for Flex, but this hasn't been added in just yet.

Your best solution would be to have a listener on the column headers and then sort the data yourself.  It isn't that hard, but it's important to be able to keep 'state' on the sort.  Plus, it'll give you better malleability to change the sorting options.

Comment: Thanks Jax. I don't understand Adobe did not copy the code (with some changes) from the AdvancedDataGrid to the DataGrid. The core logic for multi-column sorting is there, they just need to port it across to the spark architechture. Multi-column sort is fairly core functionality that many users would like to see on the DG.

Comment: The Spark DataGrid is a complete rewrite from scratch because the old charts were 'meh' at best.  Because of this rewrite, a lot of different implementation concepts have changed (like the skinning portion).  It'll come default eventually, but they need to test it out fully before releasing it.

Answer (score 1):

The 4.10/4.11 release from Apache has the methods needed. We've blogged about this here: http://blog.flexicious.com/post/Spark-DataGrid-Multi-Column-Sort.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use the sortCompareFunction property of the spark DataGrid to define a function with the multi-column sorting logic in it. It works well enough, for the moment.